# How many pairs $(m, n)$ exist?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, logarithms, contest-math

> For certain pairs $ (m,n)$ of positive integers with $ m\ge n$ there are exactly $ 50$ distinct positive integers $ k$ such that $ |\log m - \log k| < \log n$. Find the sum of all possible values of the product $ mn$.

**HINTS ONLY!**

Obviously, converting it into a simpler form is good idea.

$$\frac{1}{n} < \frac{m}{k} < n \implies k < mn < n^2k.$$

Okay, so we already have a pretty simplified form, I broke it into two cases.

Case 1: $m = n$ then saw:

$\implies k < n^2 < kn^2$, which is true for ALL $k \ge 2$ and any $n$.

So $m= n$ is an impossible case.

The remaining case left is $m > n$.

This is actually getting quite difficult.

There must be exactly $50$ values of $k$.

How should I go about this?

**SMALL - HINTS ONLY! Please don't give it away!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

We have $$\frac 1n\lt\frac mk\lt n\iff \frac mn\lt k\lt mn\tag 1$$

Setting $\lfloor\frac mn\rfloor=s$ gives
$$(1)\iff s+1\le k\le mn-1$$with $s\le\frac mn\lt s+1$.

Hence, one has $50=(mn-1)-(s+1)+1$.

Comment: couldn't we do: $mn - m/n = 50$? (+1)

Comment: With this method I got $mn = 51 + s$. But there are infinite $s$ values?

Comment: @Amad27: First, $m/n$ is not necessarily an integer (that's why I considered the floor function). Second, for example, the number of integers $x$ such that $1\lt x\lt 4$ is $2$, not $4-1=3$. Please be careful. Additional hint : We have $s=mn-51$. So, put this in the inequalities to restrict $m$ or $n$. (please note that we also have $m\ge n$.)

Comment: $mn - 50 \ge k \le mn -1 $. Still doesnt make a difference?

Comment: @Amad27: The inequalities I mentioned above are $s\le \frac mn\lt s+1$. If you put $s=mn-51$ into these, you'll get $mn-51\le \frac mn\lt mn-51+1$. From the left inequality, you'll have $m\le\frac{51n}{n^2-1}$ for $n\ge 2$. With $m\ge n$, you'll have $n\le \frac{51n}{n^2-1}$, and so on.

Comment: So $mn \le \left( \frac{51n}{n^2 - 1} \right)^2$. But that is the point, there are still infinite $n$ values that could be put in.

Comment: @Amad27: Well, why not try to find possible $n$? For $n\ge 2$, we have $n\le\frac{51n}{n^2-1}$, i.e. $n(n^2-1)\le 51n$. From this, you should be able to get $n\le 7$.

Comment: Okay I am trying to see a relation of the left inequality. We had, $mn - 51 \le m/n \implies mn^2 - 5n \le m$. How did you get: $m \le 51n/(n^2 - 1)$?

Comment: @Amad27: $mn-51\le \frac mn\Rightarrow mn^2-51n\le m\Rightarrow mn^2-m\le 51n\Rightarrow m(n^2-1)\le 51n\Rightarrow m\le \frac{51n}{n^2-1}$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Sorry, my brain is broken today. Jeez.Thanks a lot. So $n \le 7$. If $n = 7$ then it is impossible to have $m > n$. so $m=n$? And the sum is: $\sum_{n=1}^{7} n^2 = 140$?

Comment: @Amad27: I think I gave you a lot of hints... Note that $n\le 7$ is a necessary condition. You need to check if each of $n$ is sufficient using the inequalities we have.

Comment: Mathlove, I really appreciate your hints, the problem is actually making more sense now. I'l test the values. if $n=7$, why cant we have $m = 7$?we can have $m= n$ right?

Comment: @Amad27: Checking if each of $n=2,3,\cdots, 7$ is sufficient using $mn-51\le\frac mn\lt mn-51+1$ gives $(m,n)=(19,3),(34,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will help to see

$$|\log m-\log k| < \log n \implies \log m-\log n < \log k < \log m+\log n \implies \log\frac{m}{n} < \log k < \log mn$$

Where $\log$ is monotonic.